# Rails AJAX - getting a dropdown selection to populate a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, drop-down-menu, html-table, populate

I'm trying to get a selection from a dropdown to populate a table in the same page, using AJAX so that changes appear without a page refresh. I've got as far as working out the code for the remote call, and adding the custom action to the controller, but I don't know how to get the returned information into the table I've got. At the moment, the table is just looping through all the projects, but I want it to only display the info for the one project that is selected.

What would I need to write in a JS (rjs?) file to get it to process the returned information, and what changes would I need to make to the existing table to make sure that it is displaying the correct info?

Dropdown (with AJAX call):

```
<%= collection_select :id, Project.all, :id, :name, :onchange => remote_function(:url=>{:action => 'populate_projects'}) %>
```

Controller action:

```
 def populate_projects
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
 end
```

And the existing table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Budget</th>
    <th>Deadline</th>
    <th>Company ID</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= project.name %></td>
    <td><%= project.category %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency(project.budget, :unit => "&pound;") %></td>
    <td><%= project.deadline.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y") %></td>
    <td><%= project.company_id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'More', project %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', project, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Assume you're using jquery

```
<%= collection_select :project, :id, Project.all, :id, :name, {}, {:onchange => '$.get("/populate_projects")'} %>
```

then in your controller

```
def populate_projects
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    ...
    format.js { render 'populate_projects', :formats => [:js] }
    ...
  end
end
```

finally, create `populate_projects.js.erb` and write any change table content script. `@project` is available in that script.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not in a form - it is a standalone dropdown box in the index view - how would I get this to work without having to have it in a form or having a submit button? Sorry, I'm pretty new to rails so you might have to spell it out for me! Thanks!

Comment: Ultimately what I am trying to achieve is to have the dropdown menu display a list of all current projects, so that the user can click 'select project' and it puts the id of the project into the session, so only tasks etc. relevant to that project are shown on the following pages. So could I create a form that would call a custom action when it submits to put the id of the project selected in the dropdown into the session? If you could give me some idea of how to do that, that would be fantastic! I already have a custom action called select_project, but can't seem to link it to a dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Create one partial `_project.html.erb` and render this partial in index page.
`<%= render @projects %>`
On change of project just render partial with project object and update page using rjs.

Comment: at the moment, I am getting an error that says : undefined method `remote_function' - any idea why? How else can I make a remote ajax call when the value of the dropdown is changed? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I've just looked it up - remote_function has been taken away in rails 3 - how else would I achieve the same thing!?

Comment: Simply using jquery onchange event send ajax request on response just set html.on rails action `format.js{render :partial=>@project}`

Comment: For listing task based on project you can walk through https://github.com/amardaxini/dynamic_report

Answer (score 0):

In js(RJS) file you need to call partial HTML file and this file have tables That you shown here in your question.

I hope this helps you.

Thanks.