# Select Box to sort a Table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, drop-down-menu

I am fairly new to the Rails world, and I have been stuck on this problem for a while. I am using Twitter Bootstrap for my framework, and I am trying to build a basic website with a table sorted/filtered by a Select Box. I have the table created, but I am unable to get a Select Box to filter it. I have tried several things, including the DataTables gem, which did not work correctly. I don't know what I would need to use in order to make this work.

If you could just walk me through a basic website with a table sorted/filtered by a Select Box, that would be awesome.

Comment: Could you post what you have in your .erb template so far?

Comment: You will probably have to ajaxify the process.  Show us your related code.  on select menu change, update the list and re-render the table with ajax.  Similar case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327282/rails-ajax-getting-a-dropdown-selection-to-populate-a-table

Comment: So what files would you like me to post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by following this tutorial, but I had to make some changes to make it work for me because I wanted select boxes. 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax?view=asciicast

Here is my new code:

**index.html.erb**

```
  <form class="form-inline"
    <p>
    <select name="state_search" class="span2">
      <option value="">Select a State</option>
      <option>----------------</option>
      <option>LA</option>
      <option>MS</option>
      <option>TX</option>
    </select>
    <select name="city_search" class="span2">
      <option value="">Select a City</option>
      <option>----------------</option>
      <option>Mandeville</option>
      <option>Covington</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">GO</button>
    </p>
  </form>
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered span8 table-condensed"     
   id="articles_table" >
    <thead class="header">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Created_At</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <%= render @articles %>
    </tbody>
```

**_article.html.erb**

```
<tr>
  <td> <%= article_counter +1 %> </td>
  <td> <%= article.Title %> </td>
  <td> <%= article.Description %> </td>
  <td> <%= article.Created_At %> </td>
</tr>
```

**articles_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @articles = Article.state_search(params[:state_search]).city_search(params[:city_search]).page(params[:page]).limit(50).order('Created_At DESC')
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @articles }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**articles.rb**

```
def self.city_search(city_search)
    if city_search
      where('City LIKE ?', "%#{city_search}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
end
def self.state_search(state_search)
    if state_search
      where('State LIKE ?', "%#{state_search}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
end
```

So to start off, I created the table with its contents rendered by a partial, just like in the episode. I then created two select boxes and gave them names. One was state_search and the other city_search. Then, I went into articles.rb and defined those names. This is the same thing done in the railscasts episode, except I replaced the names with mine. Next, I went into articles_controller.rb and added the two searches to it, just like in the railscasts episode.
After doing that, the two select boxes worked perfectly and sorted/filtered the table.

Thanks