# Ajax call with dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327282/rails-ajax-getting-a-dropdown-selection-to-populate-a-table) question but I am stuck.
In my controller I have:

```
 def index
    if params[:sort] == 'stars'
      @projects = [Project.first]
    else
      @projects = Project.all
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js { render 'populate_projects', :formats => [:js] }
    end
  end
```

in routes:

```
get '/inspire/:sort' => 'projects#index'
```

in view:

```
   = collection_select :project, :id, Project.all, :id, :name, {}, {:onchange => '$.get("/inspire/stars")'}
   %div#normal
    = render 'projects_list'
   %div#stars{ style: 'display: none' }
```

my _projects_list.html.haml has:

```
  %div
    - @projects.each do |project|
      %div
        %p
         #more code...
```

and finally in populate_projects.js.haml:

```
:plain
  $("#stars").html("#{escape_javascript render(partial: 'projects/projects_list')}");
  $("#normal").hide();
  $("#stars").show();
```

Probably the program doesn't make sense as I am testing if ajax call is working. However, what should happen is when I change the state of dropdown an ajax call must be made which renders 'propulate.js.haml' and list of projects must change from all to just first, but is not. In my terminal I can see that call is being made but 'populate.js.haml' is never rendered. Can someone please help!

Comment: Might be a typo in your question but you're trying to render the partial projects_list, but in the question it's project_list (singular on project)

Comment: Thanks Marcus. yes it was only in question. Corrected now!

Comment: Are you sure the JS format is requested? Perhaps you should try `:onchange => '$.get("/inspire/stars.js")'` to verify.

Comment: Yup! That did the job :D @sebastian would you like to answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your Ajax call requests the JS format:

```
= collection_select :project, :id, Project.all, :id, :name, {}, {:onchange => '$.get("/inspire/stars.js")'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an ajax call you need to include:

```
"data-remote" => true
```

See [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) for more information